# How to write only one function to increment different counter variables in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a screen in flutter where,
I have three rows in a column, each  consists of:

1. text
2. IconButton(add icon)
3. text

When I'm clicking on the add icon I need to increment a counter variable and display it as Text(third bullet point)

Checkout the screenn here  : https://ibb.co/37v4rDj

But I'm writing different functions for different counter variables, I don't want that, I want to write a single function which can increment different counter variables

This is my code :

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(MyHomeApp());
    }

    class MyHomeApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement build
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("ctr trial"),
            ),
            body: Body(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class Body extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
    }

    class _BodyState extends State<Body> {

      int upactr = 0;
      int ndactr = 0;
      int othctr = 0;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: Column(
            //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 100,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("UPA"),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () { 
            setState(){
            _incrementctr;  // this function should increment only the upactr variable 
            }
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("NDA"),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
            setState(){
            _incrementctr;  // this function should increment only the ndactr variable 
                }
            },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("others"),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
            setState(){

            _incrementctr;  // this function should increment only the othctr variable 
            }}
},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _incrementctr() {
      // this is a single function which should incerement only one counter variable , any of the following :       
    //1.upactr++;
    //2.ndactr++;
    //3.othctr++;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

        void main() {
        runApp(MyHomeApp());
        }

        class MyHomeApp extends StatelessWidget {
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            // TODO: implement build
            return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("ctr trial"),
                ),
                body: Body(),
            ),
            );
        }
        }

        class Body extends StatefulWidget {
        @override
        _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
        }

        class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
        int upactr = 0;
        int ndactr = 0;
        int othctr = 0;

        void _incrementctr(int i) {
            print("pos: $i");
            setState(() {
            if (i == 1) {
                upactr++;
            } else if (i == 2) {
                ndactr++;
            } else {
                othctr++;
            }
            });
        }

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Center(
            child: Column(
                //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                    height: 100,
                ),
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Text("UPA"),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                            _incrementctr(1);
                        }),
                    Text("$upactr")
                    ],
                ),
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Text("NDA"),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                        _incrementctr(2);
                        },
                    ),
                    Text("$ndactr")
                    ],
                ),
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Text("others"),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                            _incrementctr(
                                3); // this function should increment only the upactr variable
                        }),
                    Text("$othctr")
                    ],
                ),
                ],
            ),
            );
        }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a Text field for each counter, looks like it's missing. Each text field will use its variable to display.
2. No need for outer function. in every onPressed() the specific counter should be incremented, for instance, just by calling upactr++